# How to read contents of zip file and save files

Tags: java, groovy, zip

I wish to recursively read contents of a zip file and save all found files to my hard drive.

I'm reading the zip file like this:

```
def zipFile = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File('/Users/birdy/test.zip'))

zipFile.entries().findAll { !it.directory }.each {
    def is = zipFile.getInputStream(it)
    //how do i store this stream to a file?
}
```

If a zip file has the following files:

```
folder1/test1.txt
folder2/test2.jpg
```

then i wish to store `test1.txt` and `test2.jpg` to my HD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here You go:

```
import java.util.zip.*

def zipIn = new File('lol.zip')
def zip = new ZipFile(zipIn)

zip.entries().findAll { !it.directory }.each { e ->
    (e.name as File).with{ f ->
        f.parentFile?.mkdirs()
        f.withOutputStream { w ->
            w << zip.getInputStream(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Is everything clear for You?

Comment: A couple of things: First, the parent directories of the `new File(e.name)` file may not exist. Second, why `withWriter` instead of `withInputStream`? Isn't that presuming character data?

Comment: When it comes to parent dir if You run the script in the same directory where zip is processed it will be existing. Steam changed.

Comment: Zip entry names are not necessarily one path element deep. At some point, the entry's parent directories would need to be created on the local file system, and that doesn't happen automatically when you start writing content to a file, unfortunately. You need an explicit `mkdirs()` call.

Comment: Yes, You're absolutely right but I assumed that there are not sub directories, when writing the script. Feel free to edit the post.

Comment: @cfrick, where's `e` defined?

Comment: whoopsie.  fixed.  sorry!

Answer (score 1):

With Java Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnZip
{
    List<String> fileList;
    private static final String INPUT_ZIP_FILE = "C:\\MyFile.zip";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "C:\\outputzip";

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        UnZip unZip = new UnZip();
        unZip.unZipIt(INPUT_ZIP_FILE,OUTPUT_FOLDER);
    }

    /**
     * Unzip it
     * @param zipFile input zip file
     * @param output zip file output folder
     */
    public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder){

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

     try{

        //create output directory is not exists
        File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        //get the zip file content
        ZipInputStream zis = 
            new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
        //get the zipped file list entry
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        while(ze!=null){

           String fileName = ze.getName();
           File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

           System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            //create all non exists folders
            //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
            new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

            int len;
            while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fos.close();   
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }

        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    }catch(IOException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
   }    
}
```